# Prevent submission when fields are blank and display error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have lots of different forms on my website. I want to use Jquery to:

- Display an error message if any of the text fields are blank
- Highlight the blank fields with CSS
- Prevent submission of the form until the user fills them in.

All the different forms link to the same Jquery script, so I have to make sure that my jquery doesn't make any references to a specific form (otherwise, I will have to write a different script for each form).

I thought the best way to do this would be to an [each function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop through the input fields to check if they are blank and then use [event.preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop the form from submitting and [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to highlight the fields.

The each function works but the preventdefault/addclass don't seem to work. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my code: ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/vVnGd/6/) version)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.names').submit(function(){  
          $('.names input[type=text]').each(function(n,element){  
            if ($(element).val()=='') {  
                event.preventDefault();
              alert('Some fields are blank (highlighted in red). Please fill them in');  
              ($element).addClass("error");
              return false;  
            }  
          });  
          return true;  
        });

});
```

How can I get it to work? Also would it be possible to apply the error class to the parent `<p>` tag of the input field rather than the field itself?

Comment: Pretty much everything you're doing can be done with the jQuery.validate plugin, why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event` is undefined. Catch the parameter in your submit-callback and invoke preventDefault on that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.names').submit(function (e) {
        $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function (n, element) {
            if ($(element).val() == '') {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Some fields are blank (highlighted in red). Please fill them in');
                $(element).parent().addClass("error");

                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    });
});
```

Note that:

1. `($element)` is also undefined, you meant `$(element)`.
2. To add the error class to the parent, use `$(element).parent()`.
3. This wont work if you have multiple forms. Use `$(this).find('input[...]')` instead of `$('.names input[...]')`. This way, you only validate the form that you are submitting.
4. Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVnGd/17/).

Comment: And you can do the following `if (!$(element).val()) {` this will check for any empty value

Comment: @alexn That works except it only highlights the first blank field. Is it possible to highlight all blank fields? I thought I could get it to work by moving the addClass lower down and changing the selector (see: http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/mSZSK/2/), but when I do that, nothing highlights!

Comment: @alexn After researching, I think I need to use filter(); to highlight all the empty fields (http://api.jquery.com/filter/). I have tried it, but I can't quite get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/mSZSK/6/. I would appreciate any pointers! Thanks!